# Input type Date does not have a value in page RTL and has a value when page LTR

Tags: django

I have project using the Django framework and iuser i18n to support English and Arabic.

I have created a form to add customers, and I use the input type `date` to pick the date.  It works fine in LTR but when change direction to RTL it loses the value when I submit the form:

the form model:

```
enter code here
class patienForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    class Meta:
        model = patientModel
        fields=['Patient_Name_en',
            'Email',
            'Birth_Date']

        widgets = {
            'Patient_Name_en': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Birth_Date':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'date','max':dt}),
            }
```

the view :

```
class createPatientView(CreateView):
model=patientModel
template_name='reception/patientmodel_form.html'
form_class=patienForm

def form_invalid(self, form):
    print(form.instance.Birth_Date)
    print(form.instance.Email)
    print(form.instance.Patient_Name_en)
    return HttpResponse(form)

def form_valid(self, form):
    print(form.instance.Birth_Date)
    print(form.instance.Email)
    print(form.instance.Patient_Name_en)
    return HttpResponse(form)
```

the result of the above code :
when page is RTL it call form_invalid and print:
None
username@emailaddress
Abdullah Alfaifi

when the same page but LRT it call form_valid and print :

2014-07-12
username@emailaddress
Abdullah Alfaifi

What would be the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361273/how-to-set-the-current-date-to-an-input-type-date-form-in-django